# How to send push message from Kinvey and Delphi for a specific user

Tags: delphi, mobile, push-notification, kinvey

Does anyone know how to send a push message to a particular user through Kinvey service? Today I can send Push for everyone who uses my application, but I need to send to a single user.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this comment in a [blog article](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/sarinadupont/2014/04/16/remote-push-notifications-on-android-with-rad-studio-xe6/):

> If you select Addons > Messaging > Push and select to send a message
>   to Everyone, then everyone who has your app installed will receive
>   that message. You can also setup specific users inside Kinvey and then
>   select ‘Specific Users’ and define the users you want to send the
>   message to.

Comment: Thanks. I'm reading this post, but is not complete. I did not like to do.

Comment: @user558516 have you tried to set up specific users inside Kinvey, or contacted the vendor support (forums)?

Answer (score 0):

Basically I am using KinveyProvider and PushEvents to authenticate
TBackendUsers to create new user KINVEY
In Console Kinvey created in Business Logic A Custom EndPoint as their documentation
Then in Delphi I shoot the KinveyProvider.EndPoint: = 'name kinvey endpoint';
I know it's not exactly what you need, as I am also studying the same point you thought it would be helpful to share this information.